# Convert column of seconds to hh:mm:ss - Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, timedelta

I'm sure this is in SO but I can't seem to find it. I'm trying to convert a `column`of `floats` to `timestamps` displayed as `hh:mm:ss`. Below is my attempt:

```
import pandas as pd

d = ({
    'A' : [100.4,200.2,300.3,400.6,500.8,600.9],                 
    'B' : [10.4,21.5,36.3,44.3,56.6,60.5],                                      
     })

df = pd.DataFrame(data = d)

df['A','B'] = pd.to_datetime(df['A','B'], unit='h')
```

Intended Output:

```
          A         B
0  00:01:40  00:00:10
1  00:03:20  00:00:22
2  00:05:00  00:00:36
3  00:06:41  00:00:44
4  00:08:21  00:00:57
5  00:10:01  00:01:01
```

Comment: What happens to the milliseconds? Do you want to remove them, or should they remain in the data?

Comment: I've rounded them up prior. So everything is to .0

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`round` + `pd.to_timedelta`, specifying the unit:

```
df.round().apply(pd.to_timedelta, unit='s')

         A        B
0 00:01:40 00:00:10
1 00:03:20 00:00:22
2 00:05:00 00:00:36
3 00:06:41 00:00:44
4 00:08:21 00:00:57
5 00:10:01 00:01:00

A    timedelta64[ns]
B    timedelta64[ns]
dtype: object
```

You now have the functionality of timedeltas

Comment: Definitely the way to go as OP does not seem like they want to lose information. Converting to string is not really in the spirit of the question.

Answer (score 7):

```
import pandas as pd

d = ({
    'A' : [100.4,200.2,300.3,400.6,500.8,600.9],                 
    'B' : [10.4,21.5,36.3,44.3,56.6,60.5],                                      
     })

df = pd.DataFrame(data = d)

df['A'] = df['A'].astype('float64') 
df['B'] = df['B'].astype('float64') 

df['A'] = pd.to_datetime(df["A"], unit='s').dt.strftime("%H:%M:%S")
df['B'] = pd.to_datetime(df["B"], unit='s').dt.strftime("%H:%M:%S")
```

Output is:

```
    A           B
0   00:01:40    00:00:10
1   00:03:20    00:00:21
2   00:05:00    00:00:36
3   00:06:40    00:00:44
4   00:08:20    00:00:56
5   00:10:00    00:01:00
```

Answer (score 1):

Another one-liner solution:

```
df = df.apply(lambda x: pd.to_datetime(x, unit='s').dt.strftime('%H:%M:%S'))
```

Using `apply` with `pd.to_datetime` and `dt.strftime`.

And now:

```
print(df)
```

Is:

```
          A         B
0  00:01:40  00:00:10
1  00:03:20  00:00:21
2  00:05:00  00:00:36
3  00:06:40  00:00:44
4  00:08:20  00:00:56
5  00:10:00  00:01:00
```

Answer (score 1):

Extracting the time attribute from the `datetime` object after the conversion is another way of achieving this.

```
df = df.apply(lambda x: pd.to_datetime(x, unit="s").dt.time)
```